# PHP fatal error: Class 'schema' not found in (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to execute an migration in laravel, I ran the following command:

> php artisan migrate

and **php** throw me:

```
PHP fatal error: Class 'schema' not found in C://.... on line 14
```

I am using **php** 5.4.17 and **Laravel** 4.1.*

Comment: I'm not sure but the autoloader may be case sensitive, in which case you need to use `Schema::...` not `schema::...` in your migration code.

Comment: Yeah, you righ the autoloader is case sentitive. you add the response and i give you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Composer autoloader is case sensitive, so you'll need to use `Schema::...` functions in your migrations, not `schema::...` ones.